# iOS (iPad) application on Flex/Flash Builder 4.5 - SplitView component?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, ipad, mobile, flash-builder4.5

(Disclaimer: I'm a beginner in mobile application development and I'm quite weak with programming but I'm willing to learn new things and take on new challenges. I apologise in advance if my question turns you off, or if it seems as though I haven't done any research. I did all the research I could but it didn't help me much.)

I'm new to developing iOS applications and my school gave me approximately 5 months to develop an iPad application. I have no knowledge or practice on Objective C so since Flash Builder 4.5 allows the development of mobile applications (and I have experiences with Flash Builder), I decided to develop my application on Flash Builder instead.

Everything is going fine until I was told to include a SplitView in my application. I implemented a List on the left side of the application. Clicking on any of the list items will navigate the user to a to another view but i also included and retained the list on the left side of the new view in order to simulate a "SplitView".

Initially it felt as though it will do the job of a SplitView like how it does when I attempted it on XCODE but it doesn't look or feel natural.

I found this [video](http://vimeo.com/27807575) which shows that it is possible to create a SplitView on FB but I've cracked my brains and I really can't figure out how it is done. Is there anyone who can provide me with a rough guide on how to implement this? Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:

At the moment I implemented

```
<s:Application 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"> 


<s:ViewNavigator id="MainView" left="292" width="732" height="748" firstView="views.MainView"/>


</s:Application>
```

this way, i can manage to navigate through the views without effecting the Root View Controller. this might not be the best way but it'll suffice at the moment. Are there are any better way to do this?

Comment: What kind of behavior do you want? what have you tried? can you show the code? what's the user interaction?

Comment: @J_A_X what i want would basically be how a SplitView application on iPad works. Currently all i have is a list at the left side of every single view. clicking on any items on the list will navigate a user to another view. What i'm trying to achieve is to have a view controller on the left side of the application that controls the main view on the right side like [this SplitView iOS application.](http://mobiforge.com/files/ipad-split-3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [eskimo library](http://e-skimo.com/)

It has a lot of nice mobile features like "native" look and feel for both android and iOS.

Furthermore, it features some mobile components.

I believe the one you are looking for is called `SplitViewApplication`.
You will have to download the zip file though to unveil it since it is currently not on the feature list on their website.

**EDIT**

Apparently, [Flex SDK 4.6](http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flex/articles/introducing-flex46sdk.html) also supports this feature.
 
It has been released 2 days ago. You might want to check that out as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `HDividedBox` is a [right component for you](http://www.google.ru/search?rlz=1C1_____ruRU423RU423&aq=1&oq=Flex%20HDivi&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flex%20hdividedbox%20example).

Comment: Hi Maxim, I tried to include the HDividedBox is not compatible for Mobile Applications. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: If component is not compatible for Mobile you can still use it. `HDividedBox` provides a draggable thumb between child components, if you don't need it - just use `HBox` and set the one child `width="100%"`.

Comment: There was an error implementing both HDividedbox and HBox. The error message was as such: _"Could not resolve <s:Hbox> to a component implementation"_

Comment: What IDE are you using? In Flash Builder place cursor at the end of the component name and press `Ctrl+Space` to fix this.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it, might not be the best solution but it'll suffice at the moment. I implemented `<s:Application 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"> 


<s:ViewNavigator id="MainView" left="292" width="732" height="748" firstView="views.MainView"/> 


</s:Application>`